# Object doesn't follow the curve line during animation

Tags: animation

To the left you can see an object and to the right, it's parented curve line.
When I hit the play button the object doesn't follow the line

[image]

If I put in any value in the evolution time box the object stops at
the static point right when I enter the value. But when I press play
the object still doesn't follow the line. In the image below you can
see how the object is moved forward a bit after entering "1" into
the evolution time box. But nothing happens in the animation. I should say that the object (a power industrial truck) is actually a group of smaller objects.

[image]

Comment: could you please share the file, at least object + curve? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: make a simplified version of the file and add a link in your question so that others can understand the issue.

Comment: I sure do appreciate your help. Here's a link to a really shortened version. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p8zzCtjhktIhuOs6QqrzCLJY9S1TJmXN/view?usp=sharing